# Onchange update database

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make an page where you can select a value in a dropdown select box. When the selection is made it should update the database using the selected value.
I use 2 pages one including the html/javascript and one using php.
Currently when i select something nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong?

test.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script>
    function updateDb() {
     $.post("buh.php", $("#form").serialize());
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
    <?php
        include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
        $sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER BY phonenr asc"    ;
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);       
        echo "<select id='select' name='select' onChange='updateDb()'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['phonenr'] . "'>" . $row['phonenr'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

And buh.php

```
<?php
include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
$sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER WHERE phonenr='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["select"])."'"     ;
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' WHERE unit_id='1'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

?>

Comment: What' the name of table you're selecting data?

Comment: You need to do some debugging first. Open Dev tools and head to the Network tab. Check if the request is sent, and if so, what is the response code (200,404,500 etc.) and what is the response content.

Comment: are you able to connect to blah.php, try displaying something in blah, such as the parameters your sending, if that works then you know on what page the error is

Comment: Exactly, I agree with Matanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something wrong with you `SELECT` query

```
$sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER WHERE phonenr='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["select"])."'"     ;
                           ^this ORDER here makes no sense
```

Either remove the word `ORDER` wich is a clause to order by a column, or assign it a column to order by with the correct syntax

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE yourcolumncondition ORDER BY yourcolumntoorderby
```

Then I  would like to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your a life saver thank you very much. I completly overlooked the order part

Comment: @Frank you are welcome man! Don't forget to upvote and accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

select * FROM sims ORDER ..You have added ORDER here wrongly in buh.php

```
$sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER WHERE phonenr='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["select"])."'"     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = "select * FROM sims ORDER WHERE phonenr='".mysql_escape_string($_POST["select"])."'"     ;`

remove order.